# Appropriate two way binding for checkboxes in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the data from MySQL database in the form of "1" and "0" representing the boolean true and false.These values are set in the vue component in the following manner :

```
    data(){
    return {
    form : {
         attribute_1 : "1", //attribute 1 is true
         attribute_2 : "0", //attribute 2 is false
         attribute_3 : "1", //attribute 3 is true
          }
        }
       }
```

To maintain the two-way binding I am currently using the computed properties as follows :

```
 attribute1: {
            get(){
                return this.form.attribute_1 == "1" ? true : false ;
            },
            set(newValue){
                this.form.attribute_1 = newValue ? "1" : "0";
            }
        },
 attribute2: {
            get(){
                return this.form.attribute_2 == "1" ? true : false ;
            },
            set(newValue){
                this.form.attribute_2 = newValue ? "1" : "0";
            }
        }, ...
```

These computed properties are wired on HTML code in following manner.

```
<input type="checkbox"  checked v-model="attribute1">
<input type="checkbox"  checked v-model="attribute2">
```

This works quite good for the two way binding in VUE. But there is a severe repetition in the code.

There is another way I have in mind using the @change event to track the changes in the checkbox  :checked property and change the data attributes according but It seems to be one way binding and in the Vue console values are only updated when the I refresh the VUE panel.

Is there is a better way to achieve two way binding in this particular scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply updating your template like:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="form.attribute1" :true-value="1" :false-value="0">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="form.attribute2" :true-value="1" :false-value="0">
```

and that's it. You will not need any computed properties anymore. You will get `this.form.attribute1` value as "1" when checkbox will be checked or "0" when unchecked. Also, if you set `form.attribute1` value as "1" then the checkbox will be checked by default as shown in the demo below.

DEMO:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      form: {
        attribute1: "1", //attribute 1 is true
        attribute2: "0"  //attribute 2 is false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.attribute1" :true-value="1" :false-value="0">
  <label for="checkbox">{{ form.attribute1 }}</label><br/><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.attribute2" :true-value="1" :false-value="0">
  <label for="checkbox">{{ form.attribute2 }}</label><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much. The only thing I needed to change is to put quotation marks around the values in :true-value and :false-value attributes.

Comment: This works in Vue 3!

Answer (score 4):

My favorite solution is to create component to achieve that: 
My Checkbox.vue component:

```
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="isChecked" @change="change" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        value: {}
    },
    computed: {
        isChecked() {
            return this.value === "1" || this.value === true;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        change(e) {
            this.$emit("input", e.target.checked ? "1" : "0");
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

and use it in other components:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Checkbox v-model="isChecked" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
export default {
    components: {
        Checkbox
    },
    data: () => ({
        isChecked: "1"
    })
};
</script>
```